# Is it possible to extract a token from a request cookie that was not included in the 'set-cookie' response header?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, axios, httprequest

I've been struggling with this for some time now.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is gain access to a certain token cookie that was included in the request 'cookie', but was not included in the 'set-cookie' header.

I am able to retrieve all of the 'set-cookie' cookie values via the axios response to my request. But, I am unable to gain access to the additional request cookies that are included in the request 'cookie' header.

I am looking to use this token to pass it in with my request to a graphQL API endpoint so that my request can be authorized.

The "withCredentials" does not work either since I am using axios outside of the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: How many requests are you making? With which one was the cookie you are looking for set? How was it set?

Comment: @Quentin I am making an initial request by adding an item to a cart. The server responds by sending me via the "set-cookie" header a cart token cookie and some other cart identification cookies. But, when inspecting my request with chrome dev tools, the request cookie also includes a checkout session token cookie whose key includes the cart token that was initially sent back to me by the server. That is the token I need to authorize a checkout.